# extending a typings interface TS

Tags: javascript, typescript

I am using a package in my TS application and I need to modify s particular interface in the typing.ts from the package.

the typings.d.ts of the package has this

```
export interface CreateSessionOptions {
            id: string;
            role?: 'user' | 'admin';
            sessionDuration?: number;
            data?: any;
        }
```

but I need to add an extra role `super-admin`. How can I modify this `CreateSessionOptions`

Any info would be supplied on request.

Answer (score 0):

Based on [this](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/32948271/extend-interface-defined-in-d-ts-file) you can't extend the interface that defined in `d.ts` file.

But instead create `custom.d.ts` file and add your extended interface.
[This](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/39853825/how-to-extend-an-interface-declared-in-an-external-library-d-ts/44828876) is another example that shows how to extend interface in external library