# Can I extend a non exported interface that is being inferred in my component?

Tags: reactjs, typescript

I am using a library that has components. I want to extend one of them. Here is an edited (shortened) snippet of how the button component looks like:

```
import React from 'react';

interface ButtonProps {
  /**
   * Component's id
   */
  id?: string;
  /**
   * Class names you want to give to the component
   */
  className?: string;
  /**
   * The function that is run when user clicks the button
   */
  onClick?(...args: unknown[]): unknown;
  /**
   * Component's content. Automatically detected.
   */
  children?: string | React.ReactNode;
  /**
   * Size of the button.
   * 'small', 'condensed', 'wide', 'phone-large-down-condensed', 'phone-large-down-small' and 'phone-large-down-wide' are legacy sizes. Don't use them.
   */
  size?: 's' | 'm' | 'l' | 'small' | 'condensed' | 'wide' | 'phone-large-down-condensed' | 'phone-large-down-small' | 'phone-large-down-wide';
  /**
   * Defined icon of the button
   */
  icon?: string | React.ReactNode;
  /**
   * Position of a defined icon
   */
  iconPosition?: 'top' | 'right' | 'bottom' | 'left';
}

export function Button({
  children,
  className,
  icon,
  iconPosition = 'left',
  id,
  onClick,
  size = 'm',
  ...otherProps
}: ButtonProps): JSX.Element {
  const rootRef = React.createRef<HTMLButtonElement>();

  return (
    <button
      id={id}
      ref={rootRef}
      className={className}
      onClick={onClick}
      {...otherProps} 
    >
      <span className={className}>
        {children}
      </span>
    </button>
  );
}
```

I want to extend the Button component but if you notice, ButtonProps is not exported so I don't have direct access to it. However, the type is being inferred when I use it.

I can't just do

```
export interface GenericButtonProps extends ButtonProps {
  text: string;
}
```

because the interface is not exported. So I tried using TS ability to reference a type from a variable type. Since you can do

```
type foo = 'one' | 'two' | 'three';
type bar = { a: foo; b: number };
const baz: bar['a'] = 'three';
```

I was hoping I could do

```
interface GenericButtonProps extends Button['props'] {
  text: string;
}
```

but that failed miserably. So is there a way I can extend the non exported interface?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

have you tried this `type BtnParams = Parameters<typeof Button>[0]>`?

[TS Playground](https://www.typescriptlang.org/play?#code/JYWwDg9gTgLgBAJQKYEMDG8BmUIjgcilQ3wG4Aoc4AOxiSk3STgCEBXGGCagBRzADOcAN7k4cAPQAqKWPFS4AYVyRqSWviHAAJnLhSJcnQH4AXHAEwoNAOYVx02eP1KANigFDqKEEiEBPCDY4AHcUWjguOBtgADdmKJgAC2Y0FW51GD0DOTR3TwA5HyQzCytbe0kZbLgAFRS4TDZqDGBuSKSUeGAhKGbQlOo4NgF6ODzgNABrIWTmACMOLmpsw3FuRVdJqeMACgA6Q5QoGwFzZqnqCBDqAG0AXQBKc+pL6+pKxxrlcAyNITStEy+zgAEEOLgupMUK5XP44NokHQMEhtPtVrkksBXNoiNRSpZrNQbHAAD6IYgwfbIdAwAoQRGfarOBQAZWAAC9mBBMB0FktuOiWQQBCAYa58AAaAiAxHUUbaKUEEI6JBK-BgJIZAC07hOSG12ne2tl6gV6s1Or1NgNRpu2tF4vwcHC2gIlrUuuONsNxpViOdx2YriQNnQ8IEnL8IIAItx8PARgkUiAhfI1hYo6VNM7yfgQLmCBKySKxbDC-hTfLURX-WqSxqtZ7rbbjVXzQ2PQaW777Y7y52m93va37XWyHIvsKY0hMDRUXBJu0eXy4ItONwMeIl-jzITbCWaRhqZT6YzJ8z5HAeBBIzA2kMVygEbP526d1vF4Cb3eH9muGAFbWDYSQwBW8wQBuBYNiGmBgRQAC+lBIAAHpAsCNM0rTtOwG7ULsojiGgWI4nikq5PkAhFL45HboCtFftwP7APe7QALxFrOYEMToDEbFs0wMZGXJwBx+ZSnIhz7JBKRQHwECCOQCHmLhyzyYIzxwAAUqyAAa+wAKIhr4ESEeM3CWHAOCQcgvIcUeVJoEQXRILZAA8AAStQALIADKqdwRlICZMAAHy7I8FByEQMBsFAQy7HocBueuyxJdu2hscIOhIc4zhEJgWXWTAtm5Xl4yUdRSBZXkHhUcUZV5fx2xZc10yNc4whSTJ9DqQICFwEloXpclAhgOEFV1VVNWVQ1w3lZ1xHYri6gdeIbkSGN4Tzc4G2pdwO2RUplAwP4YDMCwMC8McPhCBxPA3b4dBQAIbmnedK4BdQoW3AADPcQA)

And this might be helpful:

- [How to extend an interface declared in an external library d.ts?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/39853825/how-to-extend-an-interface-declared-in-an-external-library-d-ts)
- https://graffino.com/til/qSr3ETN5br-how-to-extend-interfaces-declared-in-external-libraries-in-typescript
- https://www.youtube.com/watch?v=45_SIDzQxeg

Comment: Just adding the reference for TS Utility Types. [https://www.typescriptlang.org/docs/handbook/utility-types.html](https://www.typescriptlang.org/docs/handbook/utility-types.html)

Comment: Excellent, this worked! and theadditional links showed me how to do a similar thing butfor Class components instead of Functional components